# What is the difference between NVENC HEVC lossless and losslesshp presets?

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia-graphics-card, h.265

There are two NVENC HEVC lossless presets:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -h encoder=hevc_nvenc
  -preset            <int>        E..V.... Set the encoding preset (from 0 to 11) (default medium)
     default                      E..V.... 
     slow                         E..V.... hq 2 passes
     medium                       E..V.... hq 1 pass
     fast                         E..V.... hp 1 pass
     hp                           E..V.... 
     hq                           E..V.... 
     bd                           E..V.... 
     ll                           E..V.... low latency
     llhq                         E..V.... low latency hq
     llhp                         E..V.... low latency hp
     lossless                     E..V.... lossless
     losslesshp                   E..V.... lossless hp
```

Could you please explain to me what is the difference between `lossless` and `losslesshp`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There appears to be **no difference** according to [What are difference between nvenc lossless and lossless-hp presets?](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1025775/video-codec-sdk/what-are-difference-between-nvenc-lossless-and-lossless-hp-presets-/) This was posted on 2017-11; the situation could have changed, so a look at source code is warranted.

`ffmpeg/libavcodec/nvenc.c`:

```
PRESET(LOSSLESS_DEFAULT,    NVENC_LOSSLESS),
PRESET(LOSSLESS_HP,         NVENC_LOSSLESS)
```

`Video_Codec_SDK_9.1.23/Samples/NvCodec/NvEncoder/NvEncoder.cpp`:

```
if (pIntializeParams->presetGUID != NV_ENC_PRESET_LOSSLESS_DEFAULT_GUID
        && pIntializeParams->presetGUID != NV_ENC_PRESET_LOSSLESS_HP_GUID)
    {
        pIntializeParams->encodeConfig->rcParams.constQP = { 28, 31, 25 };
    }
```

So there is still no difference as of answering.

I don't know why it exists if it really is the same. My uneducated guess is that the original intent was to create a "high performance" variant that hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: Thanks. I'll split it to several questions. I've already read both lossy links. The first is about `h.264`, not `hevc`, there is no code examples for `nvenc_hevc`. The second is also doesn't have code examples for `nvenc_hevc` and it's almost 3 years old.

Comment: This code in SDK will always be the same. It sets QP for not lossless presets. Of course for lossless QP makes no sense.